# Call Back button from service Android (system-wide)

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to remap the Honeycomb "Back" button to a button in my app (service) but after hours of search I'm still nowhere. The functionality must be there system-wise like the back button in ButtonSaviour (see market)

Most solutions for emulating the Back button are based on calling finish(). Not sure if it will work in my case since I have to call finish() from whatever activity I find on the foreground. I do manage to get the foreground application with the code

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(getContext().ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> T = am.getRunningTasks(5);
        System.out.println("top activity: "+T.get(0).topActivity);
```

but I'm not sure how I should send a finish() intent to that..

I also tried the solution posted here http://www.anddev.org/throwing-simulating_keystrokes_programatically-t717.html but I couldn't get around the IWindowManager (has it been removed in Honeycomb?). That solution, however, looks interesting because with that I could send KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK from anywhere, anytime.

Please let me know which is the best way to implement this functionality SYSTEM-WIDE, i.e. from a service rather than from a specific application of mine.

cheers

PS: The app is meant to run on my own rooted tablet rather than for distribution to others.

Comment: Why do you want that? That sounds not very user friendly.

Comment: Hi, I just need the "Back" button located on another part of the screen. I have a rooted device and this is personal app so no worries for distribution and compatibility..

Comment: Take a look at how Accessibility Tools are created.

Answer (score 1):

Why does people spam the thread with advises about  designs and good practices when the question clearly states that this will not be used for the market?!
 Replacing android nav bar is sometimes required in some applications, even if no more than for own pleasure (or programmer satisfaction).

try from java Runtime exec
input keyevent 4 
4 means back

button savior most likely uses hidden api, I had encountered that somewere, but don't remember now. When I will find it, I will post back.

Comment: You get +1 because as you stated if someone wants to do something in their app and asks for how to it they shouldn't get "You shouldn't do that" but some concise answer or be pointed somewhere where they can find out more.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not finding an answer to this is that this is a terribly hacky way to do things and it indicates that there is something majorly broken with the design of your app.  You should not be able to "call the back button," that doesn't make any sense at all.  In fact, you really shouldn't change the behavior of the back button at all, users get really upset when you do that.  If you have a service, and you need to send messages to an Activity, then use a messenger.  But you should certainly not (and certainly cannot) be changing the behavior of other apps from your service.  (This would indicate a major security flaw in the system, and would let you hijack someone else's UI, doing potentially dangerous, or at least annoying, things.)

Comment: Hi, ButtonSaviour does it (check it out from the market) so it should be possible. I hate the honeycomb system bar and I want to make a translucent "Back" button which I can put e.g. in a corner of the screen. Any idea on how they do it?

Comment: Do *not* change the behavior in the system.  Don't say "this app breaks Android's design pattern in a bad way, how can I hack the system to do it," that's a horrible excuse, and a horrible way to design your app.  You *cannot* change the behavior of the system through your app.  Trying to do so will use techniques which will be broken in future versions of Android as they are recognized as security violations and are being removed by the Android development team.

Comment: To be clear: the only way to change the behavior of other apps in the system should be through custom firmware, not your app, and doing so will likely get your app removed from the market (and possibly your account suspended..)

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing? Did you try Button Saviour by any chance? It does require a rooted device but it's beautiful. As for the issue of distributing, this will be a personal app. I don't need to distribute it to others. cheers

Comment: If I remember correctly, it *does* require root for full functionality.  These tricks rely on security holes in the Android system (which will be removed) that you can read about in Mark Murphy's books (for example, he has a good explanation of "clickjacking," which is related to this, iirc...).  That would be the place to start  if you wanted to implement this, but if this works for you, why not just use one of these apps.

Comment: unfortunately not a possibility, I made a custom launcher with a nice overlay and all I need is a back button, but that must come from my own app. I just wish they didn't implement Honeycomb that way sometimes.. oh well let's see if somebody else has gone through a similar problem. thanks anyways cheers

Answer (score 0):

Will the activity be open when you want to simulate the back button? If so, you could set up a timer inside your activity that checks for an exit file every 5 seconds or so. Then, from your service, create the exit file when you want to simulate the back press. When the activity sees that the exit file was created, delete that file and call finish().

As others have suggested, though, doing things this way means that you might need to rethink the app's design. What exactly are you trying to achieve?